# How i know when job occur on list view (SQL Server 2000)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I trying to write a job monitor on Listview, I get information from `sysjob` and `sysjobhistory` tables in msdb database. How I know when  job occur on list view?

I don't understand about run_time column. I want to show last job on top line and show time
when job occur as shown in picture (i have 2 job Fern and Same)

[image]

Form `sysjobhistory` show number code that I don’t know it mean such as 70000,71000 …
but I want to show time as 11.00am, 10.00am... as shown in picture.

I want to show info continuously follow time schedule recurring for monitoring JOB.

```
  public void GetJobsAndStatus()
   {
       string sqlJobQuery = "select j.job_id, j.name, j.enabled, jh.run_status, jh.message, jh.run_date, jh.step_name, jh.run_time from sysjobs j inner join sysjobhistory jh on j.job_id = jh.job_id";

       // create SQL connection and set up SQL Command for query
       using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("server=10.15.13.70;database=msdb;user id=sa;pwd="))
       using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlJobQuery, _con))
       {
           try
           {
               // open connection
               _con.Open();


               // create SQL Data Reader and grab data
               using (SqlDataReader rdr = _cmd.ExecuteReader())
               {
                   // as long as we get information from the reader
                   while (rdr.Read())
                   {
                       Guid jobID = rdr.GetGuid(0);        // read Job_id
                       string jobName = rdr.GetString(1);  // read Job name
                       byte jobEnabled = rdr.GetByte(2);   // read Job enabled flag
                       int jobStatus = rdr.GetInt32(3);    // read run_state from jobhistory
                       string jobMessage = rdr.GetString(4);
                       int jobRunDate = rdr.GetInt32(5);
                       string jobStepName = rdr.GetString(6);
                       int jobRunTime = rdr.GetInt32(7); 

                       String[] lviData = new String[]  
        { 
            jobID.ToString(),
            jobName.ToString(),
            jobStepName.ToString(),
            jobMessage.ToString(), 
            jobStatus.ToString(),
            jobRunDate.ToString(),
            jobRunTime.ToString(),

        }; 
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(lviData);
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

              }

                   rdr.Close();
               }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {

               MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
           }
           // close connection again
           _con.Close();

          // return _jobs;
       }
   }
```

The result did not meet expectations such as the arrangement of the line.

[image]

Please suggestion how to do.(using MS Visual Studio 2008 (C#)) Thank you.

And Thank you for your past help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your problem is, frankly......

Look at the first line in your last screen shot:

```
Run_Date = 20101122
```

The first four digits are the year (2010), the next two the month (11 = November), the last two the day (22).

If you look at the run time:

```
Run_Time = 112001
```

The first two digits are the hour (11), the next two the minutes (20), the last two the seconds (01).

So this job was last run on Nov 22, 2010, at 11:20:01.

Getting this info is a pretty simple case of a bit of string parsing and manipulation.

So what is causing you problems?? Where are you "blocked" and don't get to the next step??

Comment: oh so sorry i confuse a little thing.

Comment: Ok i really confuse about my project but now i know a bit of string parsing already. Form this code when i click button to call GetJobsAndStatus() The result is Fern and TestJob(last screen shot) is'n sort alternate same as shown in Enterprise Manager. What i should to do?

Comment: Yes, ok - that's the output you get from that query - what do you want to grab from that output?? It's not very clear what you even want in the end......

Comment: Ok The purpose of this project is "Message Alarm". First step i want to query Job from mssql so i want to show job occur on listview same as show in event viewer. Second step is the send message to telephone. Now on First Step. i want to monitoring job. when job occur will send info to Second Step. Do you clear ? (i want somebody help me because in my factory nobody can help me and i am very rookie) Thank you for everything.

Comment: @Fernatit: ok, my suggestion: try to think about what you *need* first - define what your screen should look like. What pieces of information do you need for each SQL job? Define a C# class that holds all that information. Once you have that, *then* you can start figuring out how to get that information and how to process the rows you get back from your select into that information that you need

Comment: ok.. I have application on client for get info form server via ODBC. should i use timer to get job info every 1 s ?

Answer (score 0):

I have application on client for get job info form sql server via ODBC.

Is it possible if I use timer to get job info every 1s and show job info on listview. *i want everything is realtime *

how to do?

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            timer1.Enabled = true; 

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        GetJobsAndStatus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuation of the previous.

I can do that on datagridview it good than use listview. I check for find job fail by use substring and check for last run date and last run time of the job.

```
public void DisplayList()
        {

                bool check = true;  // true = use oldData

                if ((oldData[0] != newData[0]) || ((oldData[0] == newData[0]) && (oldData[6] != newData[6])))
                {
                    check = false;  // false = use newData
                }

                if (!check)
                {
                    string mgs = newData[3];

                    if (mgs.Substring(8, 1) == "f")
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < newData.Length; j++)
                        {
                            oldData[j] = newData[j];
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < IDList.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (oldData[0] == IDList.Items[i].ToString().ToLower())
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(oldData);
                                SmsRtb.Text = "The job name is : " + oldData[1] + '\n' + "message: " + oldData[3] + '\n' + "Date: " + oldData[5] + '\n' + "Time: " + oldData[6];

                                //SendSMS();

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
        }
```